# Action does not trigger

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my controller signature:

```
public class CartController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        CartViewModel cartViewModel = _cartRepository.GetCart(SessionVariables.CartId);
        return View(cartViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult AddToCart(int productId, int quantity = 1)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("AddToCart")]
    public ActionResult AddToCartFromDetails(int productId = 0, int quantity = 1)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AddToCart", new {productId , quantity});
    }

}
```

Here is my route on Global.asax:

```
    routes.MapRouteLowerCase(
       "AddToCart", // Route name
       "products/addtocart/{productId}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Cart", action = "AddToCart", productId = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Here is my form which does not go to the [HttpPost] action on my CartController:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart", null, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
<div class="quantity-container">
    <div>
        Quantity :</div>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="@Model.ItemDetails.ItemMasterId" />
</div>
<div class="buy-btn-container">
    <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/buynow_btn.png")" alt="Buy"/>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
}
```

The url for the Form does resolve to my route set above:

`/products/addtocart`

Answer (score 0):

Your action name "Add To Cart" is used twice with the same parameters (two ints, and both optional to boot), so MVC cannot make the distinction when a matching URL has to be routed.

Comment: Yes but I tagged the other one with [HttpPost] attribute so that the form will use that action.

Answer (score 0):

Place your route above the default route in `global.asax`. It matches both the default route and your specific one. MVC is therefore using the one it finds first.

It seems like MVC does something strange in BeginForm since your route works for GET? I would therefore switch to BeginRouteForm instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505047.aspx

Comment: Yes it is above the default route and it actually resolves the way I wrote it on the route rules. The GET action does work by the way

Comment: Why are you using that BeginForm overload?

Comment: I will be placing some html attributes soon like @class and id.

Comment: actually BeginForm resolves correctly based on the route however. I am recieving this error "A public action method 'addtocart' was not found on controller" even though as you can see on my controller signature that I have that. I retrieved this error from the response of my post request.